# This piece of code compiles on my PC, but not on a standard C++98 compiler on a competition server

Tags: c++, c++98

I don't get any errors on my compiler and I get the correct result. I have also tried online C++98 compilers and it works there just as well. But when I check the program on a competition server it says that compilation has failed.

Can someone please tell me what to do with my compiler or what is wrong with my code? Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class P
{
    public:
        int t;
        int l;
        P();
        P(int t, int l);
        bool operator<(P next);
};

P::P()
{
    this->t = 0;
    this->l = 0;
}

P::P(int x, int y)
{
    this->t = x;
    this->l = y;
}

bool P::operator<(P next)
{
    return this->l > next.l;
}

P a[110];

int main()
{
    int z, n, x, y, tim = 0;
    scanf("%d %d",&z,&n);

    for(int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        P b(x,y);
        a[i] = b;
    }   

    sort(a,a + z);
    tim = max(a[0].l,a[0].t);

    for(int i = 1; i <= z; i++)
    {
        tim += a[i - 1].l - a[i].l;
        tim = max(a[i].t,tim);
    }

    printf("%d\n",tim);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error message from the server?

Comment: Try `stdio.h` -> `cstdio`. A c++98 compliant compiler doesn't need to provide `stdio.h`, but most still do.

Comment: No, I don't get any messages. I tried changing the header but it's still not working.

Comment: `bool operator<(const P& next) const;`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should probably add some bounds-checking for your array access (the value of `z`). Also note that you will access the array at index `z` which will be zero-initialized (since `a` is a global variable, if it was local `a[z]` would be *indeterminate*).

Comment: Thank you @MatthieuBrucher! It was 'bool operator<(const P& next) const'. It works now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know I go all the way to z. I did that on purpose. And a[z] is determined because of my constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::max` takes two `const T&` arguments. Without declaring the comparison operator `const`:

```
bool operator<(const P& next) const;
```

there is no matching operator for the operands of `std::max`.

One of the explanations as to why this works on your local machine is that your definition of `max` is not the template function, but a macro, which would not have this problem (but would not be standard C++).

Comment: Now how did the OP manage to get it to build everywhere else? That's a real mystery there.

Comment: Yes, that's another mystery. Then if he's using VS, it may be that `max` is actually the macro, which would not have this "issue".

Comment: Indeed. So the mystery is really how on earth the OP found so many online services that offer VS :D

Comment: And to be fair an old version of VS, newer versions are very good at being standard compliant.

Answer (score 2):

Your `operator<` should be `bool operator<(const P &next) const`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The copy of the parameter isn't a problem (just unnecessary), but the function not being const can cause a compilation error because of how the sort function worked at the time.  Some of the comparison stuff can expect the parameters to be const, and you can't call a non-const member function with a const object.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen see my answer.